# How to create labels using for loop in Kivy's .kv file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am working on a PDF parsing app in Kivy. I am using screen managers in .py file. In one of the screens, I select the pdf file and add it to a list, update a function in another screen ('Files') and then switch to that screen. My .py file is as under:-

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
kivy.require("1.11.1")

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.config import Config


from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

FILE_LIST = []
PAGE_LIST = []
OUTPUT_LIST = []


def add_output_list(page_name):
    for item in PAGE_LIST:
        if item[0] == page_name:
            if item[-1] not in OUTPUT_LIST:
                OUTPUT_LIST.append(item[-1])
    print(OUTPUT_LIST)


class FinalPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1


class ParsingPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 4

    def update_pages(self):
        for item in PAGE_LIST:
            self.inside = GridLayout()
            self.inside.cols = 3

            self.inside.select = Button(text="sel")
            self.inside.add_widget(self.inside.select)
            self.inside.select.bind(on_press=lambda x: self.select_button(item[-1]))

            self.inside.clock = Button(text="c")
            self.inside.add_widget(self.inside.clock)

            self.inside.anticlock = Button(text="ac")
            self.inside.add_widget(self.inside.anticlock)

            self.add_widget(self.inside)
            self.add_widget(Label(text=f'{item[0]}'))
        self.inside_2 = GridLayout()
        self.inside_2.cols = 2
        self.inside_2.done = Button(text="Done")
        self.inside_2.add_widget(self.inside_2.done)
        self.inside_2.done.bind(on_press=self.done_button)

        self.inside_2.cancel = Button(text="Cancel")
        self.inside_2.add_widget(self.inside_2.cancel)
        self.inside_2.cancel.bind(on_press=self.cancel_button)

    def select_button(self, page_name):
        add_output_list(page_name)

    def done_button(self):
        pass

    def cancel_button(self):
        pass


class SelectionPage(Widget):

    def select(self, *args):
        try:
            if args[1][0].split('.')[-1] != 'pdf':
                self.label.text = 'You can only select a PDF File.'
            else:
                self.label.text = args[1][0]
        except:
            pass

    def add_button(self):
        FILE_LIST.append(self.label.text)
        pdf_app.files_page.update_files(self.label.text)
        pdf_app.screen_manager.current = 'Files'

    def next_button(self):
        pdf_app.screen_manager.current = 'Files'


class FilesPage(Widget):
    def update_files(self):
        return FILE_LIST


class BrowsePage(Widget):

    def browse_button(self):
        pdf_app.screen_manager.current = 'Selection'


class PdfParserApp(App):
    FILE_LIST = []

    def build(self):

        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        self.browse_page = BrowsePage()
        screen = Screen(name='Browse')
        screen.add_widget(self.browse_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        # Info page
        self.selection_page = SelectionPage()
        screen = Screen(name='Selection')
        screen.add_widget(self.selection_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.files_page = FilesPage()
        screen = Screen(name='Files')
        screen.add_widget(self.files_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.parsing_page = ParsingPage()
        screen = Screen(name='Parsing')
        screen.add_widget(self.parsing_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screen_manager


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdf_app = PdfParserApp()
    pdf_app.run()
```

FILE_LIST is a variable outside all the classes (so that it can be used among the classes.

Now, I want to loop through this FILE_LIST and create labels on the next screen. But I want to do it using .kv files, so that I can keep uniformity in design across the application. My .kv file is :-

```
#, kv file implementation
#:import Label kivy.uix.label.Label

<BrowsePage>:
    GridLayout:
        size : root.width-200, root.height-200
        pos : 100, 100
        cols : 1
        Label :
            text: "Welcome to PDF Parser"
            color: [ 66/255, 103/255, 178/255, 1]
            font_size: 38
            size_hint : (0.2, 0.5)
        Label :
            text : "Select the file(s)."
            color: [ 66/255, 103/255, 178/255, 1]
            font_size: 20
            size_hint : (0.2, 0.5)
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x : "center"
            Button:
                text : "Browse"
                size_hint : (.15, .15)

                on_press : root.browse_button()

<SelectionPage>:

    label: label


    GridLayout:
        size : root.width, root.height
        cols :1

        FileChooserIconView:

            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top" : 1}
            on_selection: root.select(*args)

        Label:

            id: label
            size_hint : (.1, .1)

        GridLayout:
            cols : 3
            size_hint : (1, .15)

            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x : "center"
                Button:
                    text : "Cancel"
                    size_hint : (.15, .15)

            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x : "center"
                Button:
                    text : "Add"
                    size_hint : (.15, .15)
                    on_press: root.add_button()
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x : "center"
                Button:
                    text : "Next"
                    size_hint : (.15, .15)
                    on_press: root.next_button()



<FilesPage>
    GridLayout:
        size : root.width, root.height

        cols: 1
        on_parent:
            for i in root.update_files(): txt = "Label {0}".format(i); self.add_widget(Label(text = txt, text_size=(cm(2), cm(2)), pos=self.pos,
            id=txt, color=(1,1,1,1)))
```

I assume that when I switch the screen, it somehow create a fresh empty list. The looping code doesn't have any error, as if I hard code a list in my FilePage, then the labels appear.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not understanding your problem. Do you get an error message? What happens when you run your code? What do you want to happen when you run your code? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson I have added the full code in my question. The issue I am facing is that I am supposed to get the name of the file selected in selection page as a label in files page. But that is blank.

Comment: When I run your code, I get an error on the line `pdf_app.files_page.update_files(self.label.text)` because the `update_files()` method does not accept an argument as you have tried to provide. Also, if I comment out that line, and set `FILE_LIST` to a list of strings, your code works. Check how you are setting `FILES_LIST`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally believe that it's a sign of a bad design to place too much code into KV files. There should be a clear separation between structure of the widgets (as described in KV file) and actual logic, which should be implemented in Python. In this case we could make use of `on_enter` event to create labels upon displaying `FilesPage` screen. It'd look as follows

```
class PdfParserApp(App):    
    def build(self):
        # ...

        self.files_page = FilesPage()
        screen = Screen(name='Files', on_enter=self.enter_files_page)
        screen.add_widget(self.files_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        # ...

    def enter_files_page(self, files_page, *args):
        for f in FILE_LIST:
            files_page.add_widget(Label(text=f))
```

Comment: Hi, I agree with your point, My only concern is that I have been designing my UI using .kv files for the other screens. Is it possible to display the label- 
"You have selected the following files:" and the 3 buttons at the bottom using KV file and adding the label in between them using the for loop in Python?

Answer (score 0):

This response is based on the question title.
Also i do agree with @Nykakin that is a good practice to separate your UI logic from UI design.

I personally take a different approach on this.

**add_label.kv**

```py
<MainView>:
    orientation: 'vertical'


<MyLabel>:
    text: root.label_text
    color: root.label_color
```

then in python:

**add_label.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty

MY_FILE_LIST = [
    {
        'label_text': 'foo label_0',
        'label_color': [1, .5, .4, 1]
    },
    {
        'label_text': 'bar label_1',
        'label_color': [.2, .4, .3, 1]
    },
    {
        'label_text': 'foobar label_2',
        'label_color': [.2, .9, .1, 1]
    },
]

Builder.load_file('add_label.kv')


class MainView (BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for file in MY_FILE_LIST:
            lbl = MyLabel()
            lbl.label_text = file['label_text']
            lbl.label_color = file['label_color']
            self.add_widget(lbl)


class MyLabel(Label):
    label_text = StringProperty()
    label_color = ListProperty()


class LabelApp (App):

    def build(self):
        return MainView()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LabelApp().run()
```

This method will work if you have a small number of widgets to add on the view at once (i do not exceed about 10 ~ 30). If your data set is > than 30 points then your app might hang until is creating and adding all widget instances on the view.
Also with this method is harder to update `MY_FILE_LIST`, and that update to be reflected on UI. Is not impossible but is a little tricky to do it.

[RecycledView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html?highlight=recycleview#module-kivy.uix.recycleview), is a better suited solution for large data sets. Or if you expect  that updates on `MY_FILE_LIST` to be reflected on UI.